# How to determine the line width in OpenCV's drawMatches

Tags: python, opencv, match, feature-extraction

I'm using OpenCV's [drawMatches()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/features2d/doc/drawing_function_of_keypoints_and_matches.html) to draw the matches between keypoints. Is there a way we can specify the *width* of the lines drawn, as in my case they appear very thin.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should not be possible unless you are willing to edit and recompile openCV.

From `modules/features2d/src/draw.cpp`

```
line( outImg,
  Point(cvRound(pt1.x*draw_multiplier), cvRound(pt1.y*draw_multiplier)),
  Point(cvRound(dpt2.x*draw_multiplier), cvRound(dpt2.y*draw_multiplier)),
  color, 1, LINE_AA, draw_shift_bits );
```

This call draws the line between the two keypoints and the `1` in the function call specifies the thickness of the line (see [openCV doc](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/drawing_functions.html)). Unfortunately it has been hard-coded inside the draw function.

However it looks quite strange that you are not able to correctly visualize the matches. They are quite fine to me.

[image: some stereo matches]

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. Yes, I can visualize the matches, but when they are few you feel of zooming the image to view them better.

Comment: I see. Unofortunately there is not much you can do if you don't want to recompile opencv modifying that parameter.